# Calling web api endpoints or mvc actions works locally, but unable to do it in IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, routes

To access my application hosted in IIS I use `www.mydomain.com/myapp/Home`.

If I call some API using jquery ajax for example (in IIS hosted):
`ajax: { url: '/api/users' }`

It will call `www.mydomain.com/api/users` and returns an 404 error
I need to get something like `www.mydomain.com/myapp/api/users`

Note: it works perfectly when running the application with Visual Studio, but in IIS doesn't work. What it can be?

Changing `/api/` to just `api/` seems to work, but when I need to use `@Url.Action()`, generate the url starting with `/controller/action` and it will give a lot of work to process the result and fit to work. But I don't think this is a correct way to handle that kind of error.

Edit 1:

Now I noticed the `@Url.Action()` put the application name `myapp/controller/action` (just in IIS) instead just the `/controller/action`. So now I have two problems, clear the first `/` on web api calls, and `/myapp/` appearing to mvc actions.

Should I configure something in IIS to respect the application path?

Comment: have you tried this ajax url ajax: { url: '/myapp/api/users' } ?

Comment: @KHL As I Said, If I remove the first `/` it works = `'api/users'`. But when I use `'@Url.Action()'`? I will have to use a substring(1) or other way to remove the first `/`, this doesn't make sense. Why just in IIS this happens?

Comment: have you installed URL.Rewrite module in IIS?

Comment: No. I don't know about it, do I need it?

Comment: You could install the `URL.Rewrite module` and try if the issue still persisted then need to check the log why extra `/` has generated.